# Filtering to search for items in database

Tags: javascript, python, django, backend, django-template-filters

filters.py

```
import django_filters

from .models import *

class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model=Product
        fields=['name',]
```

Product class in models.py

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True, blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=400, default='SOME STRING', null=True)
```

OrderItem class in models.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py

```
def store(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        customer = request.user.customer
        # Returns a tuple of (object, created), 
        # where object is the retrieved or created object and 
        # created is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.
        order, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(customer=customer, complete=False)
        items = order.orderitem_set.all()
        cartItems=order.get_cart_items
    else:
        #Create empty cart for now for non-logged in user
        items = []
        order = {'get_cart_total':0, 'get_cart_items':0}
        cartItems=order['get_cart_items']

    products = Product.objects.all()
    myFilter=ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=items)
    items=myFilter.qs
    context = {'products':products, 'cartItems': cartItems, 'myFilter': myFilter}
    return render(request, 'store/store.html', context)
```

templates file (main.html)

```
<form class="form-inline mr-auto my-lg-0" method="get">
         <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" style="width:1000px; height:38px;" type="text" placeholder="Search for items" aria-label="Search">
           {{myFilter.form}}
         <button class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-rounded btn-sm my-0" style="width:80px; height:38px" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

> > **FieldError at /
> >     Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: date_added, id, order, order_id, product, product_id, quantity**

Request Method: GET

Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/?name=Fifa+20

Django Version: 2.2

Exception Type: FieldError

Exception Value:

Cannot resolve keyword 'name' into field. Choices are: date_added, id, order, order_id, product, product_id, quantity

Exception Location: D:\ecom\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in names_to_path, line 1420

Python Executable:  D:\ecom\venv\Scripts\python.exe

Python Version: 3.6.5

**After I hit the search with one of the valid products in catalog it shows me the above error.
I inferred 2 things from this.**

```
1. name is a valid field in Product class in models.py
2. the other fields(date_added, id, order etc) mentioned in the image are fields of OrderItem class in models.py
```

but since I want to search the product catalog, model field in filters.py should be set to products under which 'name' is valid field.

I want to get over this problem so that I can search items in my store. How should I amend my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProductFilter is pointing to Product Model.

But here, you are using `items` for the queryset for the ProductFilter

```
myFilter=ProductFilter(request.GET, queryset=items)
```

But items contain queryset of OrderItem Model-

```
items = order.orderitem_set.all()
```

Hence its showing the list of available Choices for the filter from the OrderItem model and not the Product Model.

Comment: Oh! just looked over it. Corrected it by assigning queryset to products and it worked. Thank You so much!